# how can onunload work properly?

Tags: javascript

The following html calls the alert when the page loads, for Chrome Safari Firefox and Opera, but I want it to be called when the page *unloads":

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.addEventListener("unload", alert('hey'));
</script>
body
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" -- you are calling alert at load time :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrapping your alert call in a function so it's executing immediately.  What you want is:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
    // do work here
});
```

That being said, it is unlikely that the browser will allow you to display an alert here.  This is a great place to save state and let the user navigate away.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
    alert ('hey');
});
```

Wrap your alert in a function...!

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload

Answer (score 0):

`unbeforeunload` is a special event that is VERY limited in what it can do.

Return a string and the browser will display the string and give the user the option to continue or not.

You can't use `alert`, `confirm` or anything else.

(At one point, in distant history, you could -- but it was abused too much.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload